# Limit of Riemann Sum as Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I'm asked to find the Riemann integral that the following limit equals:

> $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2n}\frac{5}{7-(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt{n(i-1)}})^4} $$
>
> as $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i^*)\Delta{x}= \int_b^af(x)dx $$

I know that my $\Delta{x}$ = $\frac{1}{2n}$

---

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2n}\frac{5}{7-(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt{n(i-1)}})^4} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta{x}\frac{5}{7-\frac{i^4+1}{{n^2(i-1)^2}}}$$
$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta{x}\frac{5}{7-\frac{i^4+1}{{n^2(i^2-2i+1)}}}$$
$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta{x}\frac{5}{7-\frac{i}{{n^2(-2)}}}$$
$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta{x}\frac{5}{7-(\frac{-i}{{n}}\frac{1}{2n})}$$
$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta{x}\frac{5}{7-(\frac{-i}{{n}}\Delta{x})}$$

---

I'm stuck at this point... Does it look correct so far? If so, how should I proceed in finding my $f(x)$ and my upper and lower limits of integration?

Comment: You didn't write a sum. Also, we don't convert a Riemann sum into an integral. We take the *limit* of Riemann sums to get an integral.

Comment: I just left out the limit part for simplicity sake of writing, as it is not needed when converting the sum to a definite integral (ie. finding a, b and f(x)) - at least to my understanding of how to solve these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Something happened in your calculation, I'm not sure what. I would note

$$\frac{i-1}{\sqrt {n(i-1)}} = \sqrt {\frac{i-1}{n}}.$$

So when you raise that to the $4$th power you get

$$\left (\frac{i-1}{n}\right)^2$$

You might also consider $\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}.$

Comment: why did you decide $\Delta{x} = \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Try it with $1/n$ rather than $1/2n$ and see what happens.